# Sqlite: select ('now') not works as expected

Tags: android, sqlite, date, select

I want to get the current date as `yyyy-MM-dd` from `SQLite`, I use the following query:

```
***SELECT date('now')***
```

But instead of returning the current date, it returns the next day from today.

For example, today (2015-12-01) I run the query and it returns (2015-12-02).

What I did wrong?

[Image running query + calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/593MR.png)

Comment: Is your instance set to your own time zone, or maybe to UTC/GMT?

Comment: Yes, it is set to my time zone Lima GMT/UTC - 05:00 hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite date and time functions use UTC time zone internally. In UTC the date was already 2015-12-02.

If you want to use another timezone, you need to specify it explicitly, e.g.

```
select date('now','-05:00');
```

I'd suggest to use UTC millisecond timestamps in your database layer though and have the presentation logic such as date formatting with timezone adjustment in your app code.

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Now I use SELECT date('now','localtime'), to get the current date of my timezone.